# Secure Angular JS expressions

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive, expression, xss

I'm editing an existing code that has a lot of angular js expressions which are being detected as unsafe by our automated testing system. I was able to see the article below that describes my case, but I was not able to get any specific way to solve it (I'm mostly seeing $watch and $apply). I guess what I need to know here is where do I make changes on the code?

Related links:

http://blog.angularjs.org/2016/09/angular-16-expression-sandbox-removal.html
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security#angularjs-templates-and-expressions

[image]

Sample snippets on my code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the first time I have ever heard of `$watch()` and `$apply()` being exploitable. I'm honestly at a loss as to how they could cause any vulnerability.

Comment: I think it's saying to filter the contents on the html level before passing it to the methods; if so, then how about the parts where we have static contents or none at all?  I'm also not convinced of some parts being vulnerable, I would love to get some other opinion about this.

Comment: One of the things you should take care is, when binding text in HTML don't directly bind using {{ variableName }} as it will execute the content in this variable. ng-bind-html should be used which will not render or execute the content. This will help prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: @Lex you should see my posted answer, it is definitely exploitable.

Comment: @codymikol You can run arbitrary code on your own client. I still fail to see how this is an "exploit." You aren't executing code on the server. You aren't even executing code in another user's browser. You are executing code in your own browser.

Comment: @Lex These are specifically XSS (cross site scripting) exploits, this means that some client can execute arbitrary javascript on the machine of another client. These do not exploit the host machine, but rather other clients that use the system.



Imagine as an end user you gain the ability to redirect every user of a website to another website (like a similar looking phishing website). That is the danger of these exploits.

Comment: @codymikol XSS doesn't really have anything to do with `$scope.apply`. It's certainly not specific to AngularJS. If you are not cleaning stuff that you are storing in the database, or worse, allowing `<script>`, `<object>`, etc. tags to be written to your database then no amount of removing `$scope.apply()` in your JS is going to save you from XSS exploits.

Comment: While scrubbing your database for malicious looking code is good and important, it would not save you from one of these targeted XSS attacks. A naive developer who fetches something like a description from a database and then attempts to modify that value (maybe to append some suffix for example)  say `$scope.apply('formattedDescription = "description: ' + serverDescription + '"')` serverDescription is some user specified description living on $scope.serverDescription. In most cases this will format text as `description: a description`, but a malicious user can modify this to perform XSS.

Comment: An example of the above would be serverDescription being `escaped statement\"  formattedDescription.constructor.constructor("alert(\'Just through a user string I was able to hijack the function constructor!\')")()` Given that this description is visible to any visitors of the site and that it will execute code on other browsers proves that this is a valid XSS vector as stated in the AngularJS blog and in their documentation.  They spent a lot of hours building a sandbox to prevent this, but it kept being exploited so they decided to advise users to just not evaluate user data via $scope.apply

Comment: EDIT: forgot a `;` after `escaped statement \";` and can no longer edit my post

Comment: @Lex I have made an example that better shows how an XSS attack might look in this form: https://codepen.io/codymikol/pen/JjPxKyg To an untrained angularjs dev this might look pretty innocuous and harmless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks perfectly fine. I think what you're missing is the "**passing user provided content**" portion of that warning.

In the first example the only thing you are passing to $apply is a function that YOU have defined, same as the second example. In the last example you don't pass anything to $apply.

The reason they have these warnings is because $apply can be passed a string to evaluate an expression on $scope.

In the same way that

```
{{$scope.hello = 'Hello, World'}}
```

will set the hello property of $scope

```
$scope.$apply('hello = "Hello, World"')
```

Will do exactly the same. now imagine you pass user defined content to this

```
$scope.$apply(userPassedString)
```

Now you have given a user the ability to run arbitrary javascript expressions in your apply function.

To see exactly what I mean by this (and how this is exploitable), I have created a codepen demo for you here: https://codepen.io/codymikol/pen/bGbzbvp

(You'll have to scroll down in the HTML to see the script, I was lazy and din't link it as a separate JS file \_('__')_/

Also if you REALLY want to understand how the above snippet is able to function (and where I learned about getting the function constructor in such a way) you should watch this video by liveoverflow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkL3jaI1cj0

This was made back when the AngularJS team was trying to create a sandbox around scope expressions to prevent XSS. There are a bunch of videos detailing different exploits people used to get around the sandbox. Because of how complicated creating a sandbox is and how often it was being exploited they decided to remove it entirely and just warn developers about passing user content in such a way.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! It helps a lot :)

Comment: So basically I just need to filter the variables that are being passed to $apply? Do you know any library that can do that efficiently? And is it fine to remove the ones that has no value passed to it?

Comment: You should just never pass user data to $apply. The angular team tried to implement a filter and failed many times, eventually removing it. You are not passing user data to $scope.apply, you are passing an anonymous function.
So this is OK `$scope.$apply(function(scope){ //do things with scope here })` this is NOT OK ` $scope.$apply($scope.userDefinedVariable); where user defined variable is a string and therefor evaluated in the same was an angularJS expression ==>  `{{ userDefinedVariable }}` would be in your view.